# What is the script function to select Solid Body in ANSYS Design Modeler?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, computer-aided-design, ansys

I need to select a solid body in ANSYS Design Modeler, with script, in a design with multiples bodies. With the following command I select all the solid bodies, but this is not what I need.

```
ag.bodyPick;
ag.gui.SelectAll();
```

I'm creating a script to model two spur gears engaged, first creating one tooth then making circular pattern to create the entry gear, with the following script I create the pinion but when I'm going to make the circular pattern for the gear, the pattern command give me an error, because I select all the solid bodies including the pinion, and I need to pick only the solid of the gear tooth to make the circular pattern them.

This is my script:

```
ag.m.ClearAllErrors();
ag.gui.setUnits(ag.c.UnitMillimeter, ag.c.UnitDegree, ag.c.No);

var p = new Object();

//Plane
p.Plane  = agb.GetActivePlane();
p.Origin = p.Plane.GetOrigin();
p.XAxis  = p.Plane.GetXAxis();
p.YAxis  = p.Plane.GetYAxis();

p.Sk1 = p.Plane.NewSketch();
p.Sk1.Name = "Pinion";
p.Sk2 = p.Plane.NewSketch();
p.Sk2.Name = "Wheel";

//PINION
with (p.Sk1)
{
p.Sp1 = SplineBegin();
with(p.Sp1)
{
    SplineFlexibility = agc.Yes;
    SplineXY(-1.76564478418, 24.6869398366);
    SplineXY(-1.51020858813, 24.7038816792);
    //......... spline coordinates of the pinion profile
    //......... removed because character limit
    SplineXY(5.26099091644, 24.1843849328);

    SplineFitPtEnd();
    }
    p.Ln2 = Line(-1.76564478418, 24.6869398366, -1.24843570599,17.4554120057);
    p.Ln3 = Line(3.71989256718, 17.1000701545, 5.26099091644, 24.1843849328);
    p.Cr4 = ArcCtrEdge(
              0, 0,
              3.71989256718, 17.1000701545,
              -1.24843570599, 17.4554120057);
    p.Ext1 = agb.Extrude(agc.Add, p.Sk1, agc.DirNormal, agc.ExtentFixe, 34.0, agc.ExtentFixed, 0.0, agc.No, 0.0, 0.0);
}
agb.Regen();



var PF1 = ag.gui.CreateSpot();
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Type");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Construction Point";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Definition");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Manual Input";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD8, X Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "0";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD9, Y Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "0";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD10, Z Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "0";
agb.Regen();

var PF2 = ag.gui.CreateSpot();
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Type");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Construction Point";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Definition");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Manual Input";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD8, X Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "0";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD9, Y Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "0";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD10, Z Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "34.0";
agb.Regen();

var LF1 = agb.LinePt();
LF1.AddSegment(PF1.GetPoint(1, 0),PF2.GetPoint(1, 0), 0);
agb.Regen();


var Pat = ag.gui.CreatePattern();
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Pattern Type");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Circular";

ag.listview.ActivateItem("Geometry");
ag.bodyPick;
ag.gui.PickFilter(5, true);
ag.gui.PickFilter(11, false);
ag.gui.PickFilter(11, false);
ag.gui.SelectAll();
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Apply";

ag.listview.ActivateItem("Axis");
ag.edgePick;
ag.gui.SelectAll();
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Apply";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD2, Angle");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "16.3636363636";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD3, Copies (>0)");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "21.0";
agb.Regen();

//GEAR    
with (p.Sk2)
{
  p.Sp1 = SplineBegin();
  with(p.Sp1)
  {
    SplineFlexibility = agc.Yes;
    SplineXY(1.9304744152, 30.2623156532);
    //......... spline coordinates of the gear profile
    //......... removed because character limit
    SplineXY(-5.79031304774, 30.3548985987);

    SplineFitPtEnd();
  }
  p.Ln2 = Line(1.9304744152, 30.2623156532, 0.209834175566,173.751999593);
  p.Ln3 = Line(-0.629381853016, 173.762062957, -5.79031304774, 30.3548985987);
  p.Cr4 = ArcCtrEdge(
              0, 191.250741537,
              -0.629381853016, 173.762062957,
              0.209834175566, 173.751999593);
  p.Ext2 = agb.Extrude(agc.Add, p.Sk2, agc.DirNormal, agc.ExtentFixe, 34.0, agc.ExtentFixed, 34.0, agc.No, 0.0, 0.0);
}

var PF3 = ag.gui.CreateSpot();
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Type");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Construction Point";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Definition");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Manual Input";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD8, X Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "0";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD9, Y Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "77.5";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD10, Z Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "0";
agb.Regen();

var PF4 = ag.gui.CreateSpot();
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Type");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Construction Point";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Definition");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Manual Input";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD8, X Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "0";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD9, Y Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "77.5";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD10, Z Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "34.0";
agb.Regen();

var LF2 = agb.LinePt();
LF2.AddSegment(PF3.GetPoint(1, 0),PF4.GetPoint(1, 0), 0);
agb.Regen();

var Pat = ag.gui.CreatePattern();
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Pattern Type");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Circular";

ag.listview.ActivateItem("Geometry");
ag.gui.PickFilter(5, true);
ag.gui.PickFilter(11, false);
ag.gui.PickFilter(11, false);
ag.bodyPick;          //<- Here is where I need to select only the gear body
ag.gui.SelectAll();
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Apply";

ag.listview.ActivateItem("Axis");
ag.edgePick;         //<- Here is where I need to select only the gear rotation axis for the circular pattern
ag.gui.SelectAll();
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Apply";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD2, Angle");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "2.74809160305";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD3, Copies (>0)");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "130.0";
agb.Regen();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select a single body by this code:

```
agb.AddSelect(agc.TypeBody, bodyname);
```

Here is the script:

(Key ideas: First, assign name "GEAR" to the gear body `ag.fm.Body(2).Name = "GEAR";`. Second, creat gear object by `gear = selectNode("GEAR");` where the function `selectNode(target)` is at the end. Third, use `agb.AddSelect(agc.TypeBody, gear);` after `ag.bodyPick;`)

```
ag.m.ClearAllErrors();
ag.gui.setUnits(ag.c.UnitMillimeter, ag.c.UnitDegree, ag.c.No);

var p = new Object();

//Plane
p.Plane  = agb.GetActivePlane();
p.Origin = p.Plane.GetOrigin();
p.XAxis  = p.Plane.GetXAxis();
p.YAxis  = p.Plane.GetYAxis();

p.Sk1 = p.Plane.NewSketch();
p.Sk1.Name = "Pinion";
p.Sk2 = p.Plane.NewSketch();
p.Sk2.Name = "Wheel";

//PINION
with (p.Sk1)
{
    p.Sp1 = SplineBegin();
    with(p.Sp1)
    {
        SplineFlexibility = agc.Yes;
        SplineXY(-1.76564478418, 24.6869398366);
        SplineXY(-1.51020858813, 24.7038816792);
        //......... spline coordinates of the pinion profile
        //......... removed because character limit
        SplineXY(5.26099091644, 24.1843849328);

        SplineFitPtEnd();
    }
    p.Ln2 = Line(-1.76564478418, 24.6869398366, -1.24843570599,17.4554120057);
    p.Ln3 = Line(3.71989256718, 17.1000701545, 5.26099091644, 24.1843849328);
    p.Cr4 = ArcCtrEdge(
              0, 0,
              3.71989256718, 17.1000701545,
              -1.24843570599, 17.4554120057);
    p.Ext1 = agb.Extrude(agc.Add, p.Sk1, agc.DirNormal, agc.ExtentFixe, 34.0, agc.ExtentFixed, 0.0, agc.No, 0.0, 0.0);
}
agb.Regen();


var PF1 = ag.gui.CreateSpot();
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Type");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Construction Point";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Definition");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Manual Input";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD8, X Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "0";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD9, Y Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "0";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD10, Z Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "0";
agb.Regen();

var PF2 = ag.gui.CreateSpot();
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Type");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Construction Point";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Definition");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Manual Input";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD8, X Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "0";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD9, Y Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "0";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD10, Z Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "34.0";
agb.Regen();

var LF1 = agb.LinePt();
LF1.AddSegment(PF1.GetPoint(1, 0),PF2.GetPoint(1, 0), 0);
agb.Regen();

var Pat = ag.gui.CreatePattern();
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Pattern Type");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Circular";

ag.listview.ActivateItem("Geometry");
ag.bodyPick;
ag.gui.PickFilter(5, true);
ag.gui.PickFilter(11, false);
ag.gui.PickFilter(11, false);
ag.gui.SelectAll();
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Apply";

ag.listview.ActivateItem("Axis");
ag.edgePick;
ag.gui.SelectAll();
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Apply";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD2, Angle");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "16.3636363636";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD3, Copies (>=0)");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "21";
agb.Regen();

//GEAR
with (p.Sk2)
{
  p.Sp1 = SplineBegin();
  with(p.Sp1)
  {
    SplineFlexibility = agc.Yes;
    SplineXY(1.9304744152, 30.2623156532);
    //......... spline coordinates of the gear profile
    //......... removed because character limit
    SplineXY(-5.79031304774, 30.3548985987);

    SplineFitPtEnd();
  }
  p.Ln2 = Line(1.9304744152, 30.2623156532, 0.209834175566,173.751999593);
  p.Ln3 = Line(-0.629381853016, 173.762062957, -5.79031304774, 30.3548985987);
  p.Cr4 = ArcCtrEdge(
              0, 191.250741537,
              -0.629381853016, 173.762062957,
              0.209834175566, 173.751999593);
  p.Ext2 = agb.Extrude(agc.Add, p.Sk2, agc.DirNormal, agc.ExtentFixe, 34.0, agc.ExtentFixed, 34.0, agc.No, 0.0, 0.0);
}

var PF3 = ag.gui.CreateSpot();
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Type");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Construction Point";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Definition");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Manual Input";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD8, X Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "0";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD9, Y Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "77.5";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD10, Z Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "0";
agb.Regen();
ag.fm.Body(2).Name = "GEAR";

var PF4 = ag.gui.CreateSpot();
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Type");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Construction Point";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Definition");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Manual Input";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD8, X Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "0";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD9, Y Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "77.5";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD10, Z Coordinate");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "34.0";
agb.Regen();

var LF2 = agb.LinePt();
LF2.AddSegment(PF3.GetPoint(1, 0),PF4.GetPoint(1, 0), 0);
agb.Regen();

var Pat = ag.gui.CreatePattern();
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Pattern Type");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Circular";

ag.listview.ActivateItem("Geometry");
ag.gui.PickFilter(5, true);
ag.gui.PickFilter(11, false);
gear = selectNode("GEAR");
ag.bodyPick;
agb.AddSelect(agc.TypeBody, gear);
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Apply";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("Axis");
ag.edgePick;
ag.gui.SelectAll();
ag.listview.ItemValue = "Apply";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD2, Angle");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "2.74809160305";
ag.listview.ActivateItem("FD3, Copies (>=0)");
ag.listview.ItemValue = "130";
agb.Regen();

function selectNode (target)
{
    var DM = ag.wb.AppletList.Applet( "AGApplet" ).App;
    var Nodes = DM.Script.ag.tree.Nodes;
    var count = Nodes.Count;
    var name, current;
    for (var i =1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        current = Nodes(i);
        name = current.Text.toLowerCase();
        if (name == target.toLowerCase())
        {
            DM.Script.agTree_LeftClick(current, false);
            var obj = ag.listviewSelectedObject;
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```